# Laravel access upper relationship value in whereHas condition

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an online shop and want to filter all orders with available IMEIs for the products in them.

In the `basket_products` table I have a `quantity` column and in the `shop_products` table I have the `available_imei` column which indicates how much of this product I have in stock.

The following query filters all orders in which all products have at least one available_imei.

```
$baskets->whereDoesntHave('products', function($query) {
    $query->where('should_count_imei', 1)->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
        $query->where('available_imei', "<", 1);
    });
});
```

The client may have ordered more than one product, that's why I want to replace the hardcoded 1 in the available_imei filter with something like `product.quantity`

Then final result should be something like this:

```
$baskets->whereDoesntHave('products', function($query) {
    $query->where('should_count_imei', 1)->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
        $query->where('available_imei', "<", 'product.quantity');
    });
});
```

How can I get the `quantity` column of the `product` relation inside the `whereHas` function?

Comment: try  $query->whereColumn('available_imei', "<", 'basket_products.quantity');

Comment: Just tried it, it behaves like the condition is always met and filters orders, that should not be there. I think it does not recognize the relation table and takes it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved it.
Here's the code:

```
$baskets->whereDoesntHave('products', function($query) {
    $query->where('shop_basket_products.should_count_imei', 1)
        ->join('shop_products', 'shop_basket_products.product_id', '=', 'shop_products.id')
        ->whereColumn('shop_products.available_imei', '<', 'shop_basket_products.quantity');
});
```